# Usernames in /etc/passwd

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm new to linux operating system and I've explored today  the /etc/passwd file and to my surprise I found that it contains many other user names like proxy,daemon..etc.What are all these users?Can I login using these users?
Here the cat command i performed on /etc/passwd.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:
syslog:x:101:104::/home/syslog:/bin/false
messagebus:x:102:106::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
usbmux:x:103:46:usbmux daemon,,,:/home/usbmux:/bin/false
dnsmasq:x:104:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false
avahi-autoipd:x:105:113:Avahi autoip daemon,,,:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/bin/false
kernoops:x:106:65534:Kernel Oops Tracking Daemon,,,:/:/bin/false
rtkit:x:107:114:RealtimeKit,,,:/proc:/bin/false
saned:x:108:115::/home/saned:/bin/false
whoopsie:x:109:116::/nonexistent:/bin/false
speech-dispatcher:x:110:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/sh
avahi:x:111:117:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
lightdm:x:112:118:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
colord:x:113:121:colord colour management
daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
hplip:x:114:7:HPLIP system user,,,:/var/run/hplip:/bin/false
pulse:x:115:122:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/var/run/pulse:/bin/false
brucewilson:x:1000:1000:brucewilson,,,:/home/brucewilson:/bin/bash
mysql:x:116:125:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
bharghav:x:1001:1001:bharghav,,,:/home/bharghav:/bin/bash
sshd:x:117:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
statd:x:118:65534::/var/lib/nfs:/bin/false
snmp:x:119:126::/var/lib/snmp:/bin/false
guest-MSvo95:x:120:127:Guest,,,:/tmp/guest-MSvo95:/bin/bash
```

Can anyone please explain what are these?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/750393/whats-all-those-users-in-the-etc-passwd-file

Answer (score 0):

Most of  those users are required by the OS processes to work. You can't login as one of those users because:

a. They don't have a shell as regular users does. For example, brucewilson has /bin/bash as shell, but pulse (Audio Controller ) has /bin/false.

b. There are not passwords for those users, so when the system asks for a password, no matter what you type you will never get in. You can check who has a password in /etc/shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can login as any user listed in `/etc/passwd` as of your choice.
for example, if you want to login as **proxy**, type the following command:

```
sudo -u proxy /bin/bash
```

It will asks password to authenticate the access, you can give your password only if your user account is added in **sudoers** list.

You can use the same command to login as any user in the `/etc/passwd` file.
For example, again if you want to log in as **daemon**, type the following command:

```
sudo -u daemon /bin/bash
```

and so on...
Hope this will help you.